# Moving cards between boards

Tags: trello

Is there a way to move single cards between boards? I have lists that grow into becoming a project of their own and would be more managable in a separate board.

Answer (score 15):

I've just tried having two boards open at the same time, in two different Firefox windows, and attempting to drag a card from one board to another. You can even drag the card out of the first window, so I believe that the answer to your question is "No".

However, the idea is being considered, and you could vote for it [in the Trello on Trello board](https://trello.com/card/board/move-cards-lists-between-boards/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e7103b0bc5b0c0000021a9c). I see it's in the "Next Up" list, which sounds promising!

---

**Edit**

Trello [tweeted yesterday](https://mobile.twitter.com/#!/trelloapp/status/137183687400890368) (2011-11-17) that **this now implemented:**

> NEW! Move cards between boards. Just click the 'Move' button, select a different board, and sit back in amazement.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly copy the board rename it and delete the stuff you dont want. Not an elegant solution i know.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new list and move items there (drag-and-drop). Then move the list to your target board (from the list drop down menu).